# Validate array in Laravel with all elements

Tags: laravel, validation

I show you my problem.

i have these in my form:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($movil["voz"])-1; $i++)
   <span class="data" data-repeat="{{$i}}"></span>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="movil">Movil {{$i+1}}</label>
       <select class="form-control movil" name="movil[]" data-repeat="{{$i}}" required>
              <option selected hidden disabled>Elige una línea móvil...</option>
               @foreach($moviles_inversor as $movil_inversor)
               <option value="{{$movil_inversor->id}}">{{$movil_inversor->name}}</option>
               @endforeach
       </select>
   </div>
@endfor
```

I have more than one "movil" select but checking the validations the second element lets me skip it. And, if I don't fill it out, the form lets me save without problem (when it shouldn't. You have to fill in ALL the elements).

My validate:

```
$validate = $this->validate($request, [
   'movil' => ['required','array', 'max:100'],
   'movil.*' => ['required']
]);
```

How can i fix that? Thanks!

Comment: mean to say if user select then he must select all or else its not an required field .is am  correct ?

Comment: @JohnLobo Imagine that I as a user have two mobile phones. So with sizeof I get the user's phone number. You, as a seller, have to make me an offer. This offer will always be under the user's mobile phones. (If it has 2, then it must be 2, if it has 5 then 5 ...) The case is, that by filling in the first terminal, the Laravel validation "accepts" me because it is already an array (although of an element , and not 2). What I want to do is, MANDATORY fill in everything that is requested. And that Laravel, can validate it.